# sorting dynamic array of structures with STL algorithm sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am having problem with sorting a dynamic allocated array of struct, please help me find out what goes wrong.

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

struct Box{
    int *dimval;
    int dim;

    ~Box(){
        delete[] dimval;
    }

    friend bool operator < (const Box& a, const Box& b){
        for(int i=0; i<a.dim;i++){
            if(a.dimval[i]>b.dimval[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void msort(){
        sort(dimval, dimval+dim);
    }

} *boxes;

int main(){
    int num_box, dim;

    scanf("%d%d", &num_box, &dim);

    boxes = new Box[num_box];
    for(int i=0;i<num_box;i++){
        boxes[i].dim = dim;
        boxes[i].dimval = new int[dim];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<num_box; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<dim; j++){
                scanf("%d", &(boxes[i].dimval[j]));
            }
            boxes[i].msort();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<num_box; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<dim; j++){
                cout<<boxes[i].dimval[j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"-----"<<endl;

    sort(boxes, boxes+num_box);
    for(int i=0;i<num_box; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<dim; j++){
            cout<<boxes[i].dimval[j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"xxxxxxx"<<endl;
}
```

Given the sample input

```
8 6
5 2 20 1 30 10
23 15 7 9 11 3
40 50 34 24 14 4
9 10 11 12 13 14
31 4 18 8 27 17
44 32 13 19 41 19
1 2 3 4 5 6
80 37 47 18 21 9
```

The output for the above code snippet is

```
1 2 5 10 20 30 
3 7 9 11 15 23 
4 14 24 34 40 50 
9 10 11 12 13 14 
4 8 17 18 27 31 
13 19 19 32 41 44 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
9 18 21 37 47 80 
-----
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 5 10 20 30 
201056 200608 9 11 15 23 
4 14 24 34 40 50 
9 10 11 12 13 14 
4 8 17 18 27 31 
201728 200784 19 32 41 44 
9 18 21 37 47 80 
xxxxxxx
```

As you can see, sorting inside a Box struct is good, but sorting among Box is troublesome, can anyone help explain the problem here and how should it be resolved. Thanks

----------------------**UPDATE**---------------------------------------

I know using pointer to box might be the devil, but I cannot see why, please enlighten me with reasons and examples. 
Besides, the following is a code snippet from a sample solution. Here, the only difference is that it's using an array of struct instead of a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, and it's getting the correct output

here's the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdio>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int A[12];
    int k;
    void Sort(){
        sort(A,A+k);
    }
    friend bool operator < (const Node&a, const Node&b){
        for(int i=0; i<a.k; ++i){
            if(a.A[i]>b.A[i])return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}arr[32];
```

int n,k;

```
int main(){
scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);
       for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
            for(int j=0; j<k; ++j)
                scanf("%d",&arr[i].A[j]);
            arr[i].k=k;
            arr[i].Sort();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<k; j++){
                cout<<arr[i].A[j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"-----"<<endl;

        sort(arr,arr+n);
        for(int i=0;i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<k; j++){
                cout<<arr[i].A[j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"xxxxxx"<<endl;
}

1 2 5 10 20 30 
3 7 9 11 15 23 
4 14 24 34 40 50 
9 10 11 12 13 14 
4 8 17 18 27 31 
13 19 19 32 41 44 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
9 18 21 37 47 80 
-----
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 5 10 20 30 
3 7 9 11 15 23 
4 14 24 34 40 50 
9 10 11 12 13 14 
4 8 17 18 27 31 
13 19 19 32 41 44 
9 18 21 37 47 80 
xxxxxx
```

---------------------------**-UPDATE 2**-----------------------

I tried to add a copy constructor and an assignment overload to my Box struct, but this didn't work out as expected. The error code is `ntdll!RtlpNtEnumerateSubKey() at 0x779d0725`
 Anything wrong with this implementation?

```
struct Box{
    int *dimval;
    int no;
    int dim;

    Box(){};

    Box(const Box& another){
        no = another.no;
        dim = another.dim;
        dimval = new int[no];
        memcpy(dimval, another.dimval, dim*sizeof(int));
    }

    Box& operator = (const Box& another){
        if(this != &another){
            no = another.no;
            dim = another.dim;
            int* tmp = new int[no];
            delete [] dimval;
            dimval = tmp;
            memcpy(dimval, another.dimval, dim*sizeof(int));
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~Box(){
        delete[] dimval;
    }

    friend bool operator < (const Box& a, const Box& b){
        for(int i=0; i<a.dim;i++){
            if(a.dimval[i]>=b.dimval[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void msort(){
        sort(dimval, dimval+dim);
    }

} *boxes;
```

Comment: Please avoid pointers (new/delete)

Comment: why? I wanted a dynamic array so have to use pointers new

Comment: `std::vector` is the way you write dynamic array in C++.

Comment: You doing it wrong. Example: int main() { Box it; } // crash

Comment: And what you probably want to sort Box is `std::sort( boxes, boxes + numBoxes, []( Box const& lhs, Box const& rhs ) { return std::lexicographical_compare( lhs.dimval, lhs.dimval + lhs.dim, rhs.dimval, rhs.dimval + rhs.dim ) } )`

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: `please help me find out what goes wrong` No. Ask a concrete question. SO is not for mentoring or "guiding".

Comment: @Daniel What's to explain?  There's a standard library function for comparing two sequences; you should use it.  (Unlike you `<` operator, it actually does define a strict weak order, so is legal.)

Comment: If you have two boxes, `a` and `b`, both empty, you'll have both `a < b` and `b < a`. This is a violation of `sort`'s requirements on the ordering relation.

Comment: @molbdnilo Anytime two boxes are equal, he'll have `a < b` and `b < a`; there are lots of other cases where this will occur as well.  The rules for the comparison operator are `a < b` implies `!(b < a)`, and `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` defines an equivalence relationship.

Comment: Does anyone know how to debug today?  It it a lost art?  Is debugging illegal now, some law?

Comment: @MartinJames: Where have you been for the past 10 years? Hiding under a rock?!

Comment: @JamesKanze, I guess < isn't so much pain here, the sample solution I provided up there obtained the expected otucome, so I guess sort shouldn't be stuck in this matter. what I wanted to know is why pointer to dynamically allocated array doesn't work in this case when a static array can

Comment: @JamesKanze I know, I just picked the simplest possible case.

Comment: @Daniel Because the actual array copies and assigns correctly, the pointer doesn't.  Use `std::vector` if you don't know the size at compile time.  Anything else just requires a lot of extra error prone work.

Comment: @Daniel Your implementation of `<` will _not_ work, unless you hit it lucky with the values.  It's not a legal comparison function.

Comment: @JamesKanze thanks for your input. vilation of three is the killer, I deleted destructor and everything is fixed. the use of < may be controversial, in fact this is an ACM exercise, and as long as it guarantees latter box in the array is no smaller(component wise smaller) than the former box, it's fine. I don't care about other orderings.

Comment: @Daniel Removing the destructor is _not_ the answer.  If you use dynamically allocated memory, rather than `std::vector`, you need to provide a copy constructor, a copy assignment operator and a destructor.  I would recommend a `swap` function as well, and a specialization of `std::swap`.  And whether you care about the orderings or not, `std::sort` does; it isn't guaranteed to work correctly if your comparison operator violates its requirements.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I added all components of Rule of Three, but it doesn't work out. Could you enlighten me which part of the implementation is wrong.

Comment: @Daniel The default constructor and the `<` operator.  The default constructor doesn't initialize the pointer, so doing just about anything with it is undefined behavior.  And the `<` doesn't define a strict weak ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obvious why the ordering is incorrect. Your `operator <` is wrong, it should return `true` as soon as one element is less than the other.

As for the data corruption, it's because you violated the ["rule of three"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) - you have a custom destructor but not a copy constructor or assignment operator. `sort` makes *copies* of elements that it sorts, and when the destructor hits it deletes the pointer it was holding. This results in undefined behavior.

**Edit:** the reason the code works with a fixed array but not a pointer is that the default copy constructor and assignment operators will make a full copy - when the original gets destroyed, it doesn't mess up the copies or invalidate their memory.

Your "fix" may appear to work, but now you've got a memory leak. Nobody is ever going to `delete` those pointers.

One other point about `operator <`, it should *never* return true with `A=B; if(A<B)` but yours does.

Comment: no that's not the way < is defined in my context. Here I wanted < to mean a component wise small. i.e., every element in a Box is smaller than that in another Box

Comment: @Daniel, OK I guess that's legit, as long as the result is always consistent.

Comment: @Daniel Which doesn't provide a strict weak ordering.

Comment: The illegal comparison operator could also cause the problem, since it could easily lead to `sort` going out of bounds, and copying from one into another.  (But the violation of the rule of three is the killer.  All because he didn't use `std::vector`.)

Comment: @MarkRansom  I tried deleting the destructor and it worked! Thanks so much I didn't know this rule and it turned out to be nothing related to dynamic array..

Comment: @Daniel: It has everything to do with your dynamic arrays.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, well I mean my implementation of my dynamic Box arrays is not correct, but it doesn't mean that dynamic array won't work.

Comment: @Daniel: If your amazing conclusion is that dynamic arrays are not fundamentally broken in C++, and that the fault must _actually_ be in _your_ code, then... wow, you're right!